# How to configure AWX for using an unreleased version of Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have installed AWX using [the galaxy role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/awx) obtained with `ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.awx`.

It installs the *devel* branch of awx, however jobs still use the stable version of ansible.

Is there a way to control the version of ansible used by jobs when running playbooks from AWX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue leveraging virtualenvs as per an hint from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/awx-project/AlWbCrlpIC0

So it was a matter of creating a virtualenv on docker containers and enabling it for the organization:

```
docker exec -it awx_web bash

virtualenv /var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27
yum install -y gcc
yum install -y python-devel
/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27/bin/pip install python-memcached psutil
/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27/bin/pip install -U "ansible == 2.7.0"

exit

docker exec -it awx_task bash

virtualenv /var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27
yum install -y gcc
yum install -y python-devel
/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27/bin/pip install python-memcached psutil
/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27/bin/pip install -U "ansible == 2.7.0"

exit

curl  -u 'admin:password' -X PATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1/api/v2/organizations/MYORG/ -d '
{
    "custom_virtualenv": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible27"
}
'
```